# Unable to increment PHP array variable in object

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart

I'm adding to my shopping cart like this:

```
function addItem($id, $qty="1"){
    if (($this->isInCart($id))  == false){ 
        $this->cart[] = array( 'id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
    } else{
        $this->cart[$id]['qty']++;
    }
}
```

If an item is already in my cart I simply tell the method to increment the current $id by one but this doesn't seem to work with these calls:

```
$basket->addItem('monkey','200');
$basket->addItem('dog', '10');
$basket->addItem('dog');
```

On the second addition of the dog item the following function reports only 10 dogs in my basket:

```
function numberOfProduct($id){
    unset($number);
    foreach($this->cart as $n ){
        if ($n['id'] == $id){           
            $number = $number + $n['qty'];
        }
    }
    return $number;
}
```

I'm sure the problem lies with my incrementing the array in the addToBasket method but when I use the exact same method in procedural coding it works fine.

I'm really rather stuck.

edit:  Is in cart method as requested

```
function isInCart($id){
    $inCart=false;
    $itemsInCart=count($this->cart);
    if ($itemsInCart > 0){
        foreach($this->cart as $cart){
            if ($cart['id']==$id){
                return $inCart=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
    return $inCart;
}
```

Comment: `$this->cart[$id]['qty']++;` should be `$this->cart[$id]['qty'] += $qty;`

Comment: Can you show us the `isInCart` method?

Comment: @JosephSilber Why `+=`, not `++`? Im learning PHP and i want to know when not to use `++`.

Comment: @Kamil - Because using `++` means you're ignoring your input parameter `$qty` when you add something to your cart that's already there. Step through your code if somebody adds 10 monkeys to their cart, then another 10 monkeys. What will happen?

Comment: @nickb I know that. I thought use of `++` on associative array which is in object may not work in PHP or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add it to the array, you're using numeric keys and not your ID value:

```
$this->cart[] = array( 'id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
```

Change it to:

```
$this->cart[$id] = array( 'id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
```

Incorporate this change into your `isInCart()` method, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had to make a few other changes to my foreach loops but the fact I was indexing by number and not id totally slipped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
function addItem($id, $qty="1"){
...
    $this->cart[$id]['qty']++;
...
```

You set the second parameter of the function to be a string. When you called the functions, again, you passed in a string.

```
$basket->addItem('monkey','200');
$basket->addItem('dog', '10');
$basket->addItem('dog');
```

If I have some string `$string = "123"` and I try to increment that with `$string++`, I'm not incrementing the numeric value of it. Remove the quotations from the numbers and it should work as expected

```
function addItem($id, $qty=1){
if (($this->isInCart($id))  == false){ 
    $this->cart[] = array( 'id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
} else{
    $this->cart[$id]['qty']++;
}
}
```

And call the function like

```
$basket->addItem('monkey',200);
$basket->addItem('dog', 10);
$basket->addItem('dog');
```

If you need a number, it's best to just use a number. I could understand using a string if `$qty` was coming from user input, but if that's the case, you'd need to use `$qty = intval($qty)` to get the numeric version of it.